# xml error while loading mp3 player

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm having an error while loading an mp3 player, here is what I getting when hitting Ctrl+Enter.

> ```
> TypeError: Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.
>   at moviesound_fla::MainTimeline/getsongs()
>   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>   at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
> ```

This is the xml I used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<songs>

<song atitle="Blind Willie" aurl="blind_willie.mp3" />

<song atitle="Wayfaring Stranger" aurl="wayfaring_stranger.mp3" />

<song atitle="Come, Thou Fount of Every Blessing" aurl="come_thou_fount.mp3" />

<song atitle="Give Me Jesus" aurl="give_me_jesus.mp3" />

</songs>

</xml>
```

Here is my action script

```
var getfile:URLLoader=new URLLoader(new URLRequest('song.xml'));

var amountofsongs:int=0;
var currentsong:int=0;
var songlist:XML = new XML();
var sc:SoundChannel=new SoundChannel();

getfile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getsongs);
n_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,n_song);
b_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,b_song);

function getsongs(e:Event):void {
    songlist = XML(e.target.data);
    amountofsongs = songlist.song.length()-1;
    playsong();
}

function n_song(e:MouseEvent):void {
    currentsong++;
    playsong();
}
function b_song(e:MouseEvent):void {
    currentsong--;
    playsong();
}

function playsong():void{
    sc.stop();
    if (currentsong>amountofsongs){
        currentsong=0;
    }if (currentsong<0){
        currentsong=amountofsongs;
    }
    song_txt.text=songlist.song[currentsong].@atitle;
    var song:Sound=new Sound(new URLRequest(songlist.song[currentsong].@url));
    sc=song.play();
    sc.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,songend);
}
function songend(e:Event):void {
    e.target.stop();
    currentsong++;
    playsong();
}
```

There are only two buttons which is previous (b_btn) and next (n_btn)

Is there any errors on this action script or it may only work after placed it on a webpage?

Comment: < ?xml version='1.0'?>
take the space out before the first ? and remove the </xml>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct XML-file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<songs>
    <song atitle="Blind Willie" aurl="blind_willie.mp3" />
    <song atitle="Wayfaring Stranger" aurl="wayfaring_stranger.mp3" />
    <song atitle="Come, Thou Fount of Every Blessing" aurl="come_thou_fount.mp3" />
    <song atitle="Give Me Jesus" aurl="give_me_jesus.mp3" />
</songs>
```

There is no need to use `</xml>`

Comment: yes that worked but then showing something like this..
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
 at moviesound_fla::MainTimeline/playsong()
 at moviesound_fla::MainTimeline/getsongs()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: `songlist.song[currentsong].@url` 
You name an attribute `aurl`, but try to get an attribute called `url`. Try this:
`songlist.song[currentsong].@aurl`

Comment: Hey its working :) Thanks a lot Emin, you found the mistake I made.